# Placing equal sign just below the equal sign of previous line

Tags: equations, amsmath

How can I place the equal sign of the second line just below the equal sign of the first line in the following command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Z = X+Y\\ =\text{A little big line than X+Y}
\label{Eq1} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a `&` before each `=` sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    Z &= X+Y\notag\\ 
    &=\text{A little big line than X+Y}\label{Eq1} 
\end{align}

Ref: \eqref{Eq1}.
\end{document}
```

I also recommend http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref. The video https://youtu.be/LFrdqQZ8FFc might also be helpful.